# How to pull Triac gate to ground with an NPN transistor with AC present

Tags: transistors, ground, triac

I am trying to figure out in this circuit, which lets the Triac `170` to conduct normally, which prevents an engine from firing, how to use an NPN transistor to replace the seat switch `154`, but I assume there is AC voltage on the `112a` line, and I know that AC would not play nicely with the transistor.

[image]

Comment: As an aside you can get opto-coupled triacs, like this http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/301912.pdf

Comment: An opto triac would replace `170`? My experience was I could not get them to be normally conducting.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, so you could clamp the 112a node with an opto-triac or replace the whole circuit. As I presume you now have a go/nogo digital signal.

Comment: I am a bit confused on what would power the led side then since it's supposed to default to grounding the magneto out with the control circuitry being off.

Comment: Would this replace the entire circuit? Supposedly it's normally closed: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/semi_eng_pwr1b_aqz40-1075815.pdf

Comment: The mosfet-ssr is as you describe normally closed, you will have to check what voltage rating your original 170 had to be sure.

Comment: The capacitors in the schematic were listed as 400V, so I believe that is the max voltage. However, I am unsure of the current; when I tried normally closed SSR's before, they were destroyed flipping the flywheel over by hand.

Comment: I am doubtful you over-currented you ssr by hand cranking most likely got taken out by large voltage pulse on magneto line. However I can only speculate without knowing the specifics.

Comment: I just measured, and I got a max current of 630mA AC on the primary winding with my meter in series. So that is definitely why none of my SSRs have survived. This was done using the pull rope and electric start. Maybe a mechanical relay is the only solution?

Comment: @aviatorken89 Not the only solution but it might be the best solution.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am just worried about vibrations from the engine ruining the relay over time, hence my desire for solid state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the transistor to switch a small relay. Or use a MOSFET-output SSR. Both those solutions also avoid any issues with where the grounding is.

As this is apparently lifted from a patent for a safety device - if your application is similar be sure to undertake a proper engineering review of the safety aspects. Keep in mind that semiconductors most typically fail on (but can also fail off or the connections can go open).

Edit: I am suggesting you replace the switch with the SSR- 400V or 600V units can be found, such as the [TLP797J](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=17109&prodName=TLP797J). You have to confirm that the voltage rating is adequate. This particular one can switch 100mA.

In the case of the relay you can choose whether to use a normally open or normally closed contact of a sealed SPDT relay, and replace the entire circuit. I assume they didn't do that in the patent for some reason (perhaps just the wiring) and I would want to figure out exactly why.

Again, the safety aspects need to be examined carefully at a system level as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Would it replace the entire circuit, or where would it be placed exactly. (Not looking for relay based solutions, only solid state)

Comment: Comment on your last edit: a 100mA rating won't be enough as I just measured the current.

Comment: 100mA should be enough to shunt out the gate of the triac with 22K in series. It's not enough to replace the triac.